# Instance Variables with web based project

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working with a Spring web project but I'm facing a problem with an instance variable, I use a List to store a report data, when a user request this report I store this List in order to use it later for an Excel generation, but when another user requests the same report the List is re-write with the new data requested and when the first user download the report, it comes with the data that was requested form the second user.

My class:

```
public class foo{
  List<Service> services;

  GetMapping({"/Report/Detail"})
  String getReport(Parameters params, ModelMap model){
    services = new ArrayList<>();
    //A lot of stuff
    services = serviceRepository(params);
    //A lot of stuff
    model.addAttribute("services",services)
    return "ReportDetail";
  }

  GetMapping({"/Report/Detail/Excel"})
  byte[] getExcelReport(){
    //Using the List<services> here to download the report
    //this List is getting modified by the second user
    byte[] excelReport = excelService(services);

    return excelReport;
  }

}
```

I don't want to do major changes because the class is too large, it works perfect but I have this problem and I'm looking for a workaround.

Any advice will apreciate.

Best!

Comment: Every time a request is made your `getReport` method is called, and the statement `services = new ArrayList<>();` wipes your list. If you want to keep it, you should pass your `List`'s data to another object (preferrably static) to use it later on, before the end of the method.

Comment: From the question, it's likely that the OP will want data from reports across all instances. If he wants to group by session then he should edit the question to inform this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a user sends a request to `/Report/Detail` you overwrite the services list. If you want each user to have their own list then you have to use a different approach. For example you could use a Map that stores users (key should uniquely identify the user) and their respective lists.

```
Map<UserKey, List<Service>> services;
```

And later in the method get the correct list by

```
List<Service> userServices = services.get(userKey);
```

In case of distributed application, you would of course have to use a distributed map (possibilities include for example Hazelcast or Ehcache)

Comment: Hi @Janar that is a great idea, so I can request the user from the session and then take the List from the Map and then do the stuff, thanks a lot!!